# String.join array from last element

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a scenario where I am getting a comma separated string LastName, FirstName. I have to convert it into FirstName LastName.

My code is below:

```
Public static void main(string [] args)
{
      var str = "Lastname, FirstName":
      var strArr = str.Split(',');
      Array. Reverse(strArr);
      var output = string.join(" ", strArr);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, like in one line or using LINQ?

Comment: Like `output = strArr[1] + " " + strArr[0];` ? By the way you are not removing the white space in front of `FirstName` value, add a `Trim()` to your string instances to do that.

Comment: don't forget to remove whitespaces after splitting your string

Comment: @igor I had done that intially but it failed as sometimes I am getting string.empty or only first name..

Comment: Maybe this question should be migrated to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is already a Reverse extension method for IEnumerables:

```
var output = string.Join(" ",str.Split(',').Reverse());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Aggregate and Trim your names after splitting, you do not need reversing.

```
 str.Split(',').Aggregate((lname, fname) => fname.Trim() + " " + lname.Trim())
```

Answer (score 1):

This takes care of a lot of the various edge cases. You mentioned one but did not include it in your initial question so I assume there could be others.

```
var tests = new[]{"Lastname, FirstName", "Lastname, ", ", FirstName", "Lastname", "FirstName"};
foreach(var str in tests)
{
    var strArr = str.Split(new[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
        .Reverse()
        .Select(x => x.Trim());
    var output = string.Join(" ", strArr);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wQSgHz)

Answer (score 0):

Below is my new code:

```
Public static void main(string [] args)
    {
          var str = "Lastname, FirstName":
          var strArr = str.Split(',').Select(p=>p.Trim()).ToArray();
          var output = string.join(" ", strArr.Reverse());
    }
```